# 1D diffusion: two opposing currents with 'flux continuity' and 'no flux' at edges

Tags: diffusion

Consider two currents with diffusion coefficient  $D$, and drift velocities $v$ and $u$ in opposite directions:

[image]

At steady state:

$\frac{d^2 c_v(x)}{dx^2}=\frac{v}{D}\frac{dc_v(x)}{dx}\rightarrow c_v(x)=C_v e^{\frac{v}{D}x}+A$

$\frac{d^2 c_u(x)}{dx^2}=-\frac{v}{D}\frac{dc_u(x)}{dx}\rightarrow c_u(x)=C_u e^{-\frac{u}{D}x}+B$

I wish to implement two boundary conditions:

1.'No flux' at $x=L_u,L_v$.

2.Continuity in the flux at $x=0$.

The first condition yields that $A=B=0$.

The second condition however, only provides $0=0$, and I cannot find $C_u,C_v$. This happends because in the 1d case, mathematically demanding 'no flux' at a point, yields that the flux is zero everywhere, which is not the physical case here.

Can anyone highlight a mathematical method to overcome this problem and find the constants of integration $C_u,C_v$ for the given physical case?

Comment: Is $c_u$ the flux? Wouldn't no flux at $x$ give $C_u e^{-ux/D}+B+C_ve^{vx/D}+A=0$?

Comment: the $C_u,C_v$ are the concentration profiles

Comment: Is that like instantaneous 1D number density or something?